# I need a custom permalink for my website

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have following scenario:

```
my-domain-name.com/google.com

my-domain-name.com/twitter.com
```

I need a custom permalink structure to pass `google.com` or `twitter.com` to `domain_name` query variable.

I have tried following code:

```
add_rewrite_tag('%domain_name%', '([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_rule('^/([^/]*)/?','index.php?domain_name=$matches[1]','top');
```

But not working

For better example Check this site: `http://currentlydown.com/facebook.com` I am trying to do the similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by just one line of code. I am thankful to @rifi2k for long discussion and proposing different solutions.

Here is the solutions:

Add following code to functions.php

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%domain_name%', '([a-z]{1,60}\.[a-z]{2,})');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Then from permalink settings, select `Custom Structure` and add newly created tag by only in our case its `/%domain_name%/` save settings.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I should assume that you were issuing your examples inside of the init hook, but if not that is the reason they weren't working for you.

So inside functions.php

```
function sd_rewrite_rules() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%domain_name%', '([^&]+)');
  add_rewrite_rule('^/([^/]*)/?','index.php?domain_name=$matches[1]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'sd_rewrite_rules', 10, 0);
```

Then if you wanted to retrieve the query variable to do something with it, you would do something like this in a page template file using the $wp_query global.

```
$domain_value = $wp_query->query_vars['domain_name'];
```

Everything you would want to know plus more can also be located by reading all about the Rewrite_API and it has tons of examples of doing other things you might find interesting or relevent.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have done the same thing. The rules are inside `init` hook.

Comment: But somehow its not working.

Comment: So did you ever flush the rewrite rules after adding this, goto the permalinks page and save?

Comment: Then next step is just forcing the issue https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite about 3/4 of the way down there is a section about non-wp rewrite rules, also you can just access the wp_rewrite object and push rules directly to it, but always you need to flush the rewrite rules after making changes because they are cached heavily and need forced into being flushed by saving the permalinks page or using wp-cli

Comment: flush_rewrite_rules( true ); Just don't leave that in your code, immediatly take it back out after loading the frontend one time.

Comment: Done that as well. Used flush_rewrite_rules() too. When I hit the URL for example: `mydomain.com/facebook.com` the search result page get open with `NOTHING FOUND`  default no search result fond text and below that search box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87866/discussion-between-rifi2k-and-sd).